# Search column and display row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I need to publish individual's exam result from this google sheet.[image] [Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1L1Qu6QCaDucr4Jy5eOAnQkX-wpYjz6eevqAMzBc72iQ/edit?usp=sharing). I've found a code that can do this if I run the app URL with "?id=1" [like](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwSDbNJHiRkuYu79BbbZcYXcrsfuA1b88BuhTGIPqjBqdRsj98/exec?id=1) but it displays only the name. I need to show the marks (Column C to G) also. The code I used is

```js
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1L1Qu6QCaDucr4Jy5eOAnQkX-wpYjz6eevqAMzBc72iQ/edit#gid=0");
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

function doGet(e){
 return search(e) ;
}  

function doPost(e){
 return search(e) ;
}  


function search(e){
 var id = e.parameter.id;
  
  var values = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow(),sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  
  for(var i = 0;i<values.length; i++){
    
    if(values[i][0] == id ){
      i=i+2;
      
      var name = sheet.getRange(i,3).getValue();
      return ContentService.createTextOutput(name).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT);
    }
  }
  return ContentService.createTextOutput("Id not found").setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT);
  
}
```

How can I show the whole row instead of a single cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me like a charm

```
/**
 *
 * @param {*} e
 */
function search(e) {
  var id = e.parameter.id;

  var values = sheet
    .getDataRange()
    .getValues()
    .filter(function(row) {
      return row[0] == id;
    });

  var content = JSON.stringify(values);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(content).setMimeType(
    ContentService.MimeType.TEXT
  );
}
```

I can expand the sheet as I need and I don't need charge the script at the same time

If you expect to return `"Id not found"` try

```
var content = values.length ? JSON.stringify(values) : "Id not found";
```

instead.

Comment: Many users will use this at a time and the main sheet can't be seen by all of them. Will it be okay there?

Comment: Yep! It should be fine.

Comment: I don't know app script much. So please don't mind if it's a foolish question.

The output should say "Not found" if nothing matches the ID but it shows only [ ]. How can I fix it?